# Mplayer infinite loop on each file within a playlist

Tags: loops, playlist, mplayer

Say I have a text file, `animations.playlist`, which contains the names of three animations:

```
anim1.avi
anim2.avi
anim3.avi
```

I would like to make a single call to mplayer so that `anim1.avi` is played on infinite loop until I hit `>`, then `anim2.avi` is played on infinite loop until I hit `>`, and then finally `anim3.avi` is played on infinite loop until I hit either `>` or `q`.

However, it seems the `-loop` option applies to the list as a whole, not to each individual file. So when I try:

```
mplayer -loop 0 -playlist animations.playlist
```

I get

```
anim1.avi, anim2.avi, anim3.avi,
anim1.avi, anim2.avi, anim3.avi,
anim1.avi, anim2.avi, anim3.avi, ...
```

but I really want

```
anim1.avi, anim1.avi, anim1.avi, ...
anim2.avi, anim2.avi, anim2.avi, ...
anim3.avi, anim3.avi, anim3.avi, ...
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can do it with SMPlayer (v. 16.11.0). First, create an ordinary playlist of your animations. Then, instead of toggling the `Repeat` button in the playlist window, toggle the `Repeat` item under in the `Play | A-B Section` menu for each animation you want on infinite loop. Save out the playlist.

The playlist can be run from the command line:

```
smplayer <playlist>
```

Incidentally, I don't know how SMPlayer knows which videos to play on repeat, because it doesn't look like that information is stored within the playlist file itself.